# What function is C-c C-v bound to in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode, spacemacs

I am new to Emacs working through the [Org-mode beginning at the basics](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org4beginners.html) tutorial.
The "Working with todo items" part of the tutorial uses a C-c C-v binding.
But C-c C-v is not working on my Spacemacs.  And it is not listed in describe-bindings:

```
SPC h d b
pattern: C-c C-v
"Prefix Command" is a keyboard macro.
Macro: P r e f i x SPC C o 2*m a n d
```

Similar results in emacs mode:

```
C-z
C-h b
pattern: C-c C-v
"Prefix Command" is a keyboard macro.
Macro: P r e f i x SPC C o 2*m a n d
```

C-c C-v doesn't work in Spacemacs mode nor Emacs mode.

What function is C-c C-v supposed to be bound to?

Is "C-c C-v" deprecated or a typo?

Is there an on-line resource that lists all the default Emacs key bindings?

I am running Emacs 25.2.1 with Spacemacs on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be bound to `org-show-todo-tree`, but the binding was changed back in 2010: `C-c C-v` is now a prefix key for various org-babel functions.

You can call `org-show-todo-tree` with `M-x org-show-todo-tree RET` or you can install your own binding to `org-show-todo-tree` (the function is still around); or you can use `C-c / t` which shows a sparse tree of TODO items in the current buffer. In this last case, `C-c /` is bound to `org-sparse-tree` which gives you a bunch of options: `t` selects the TODO case, but you might want to experiment with the other options.

EDIT: BTW, I found all this using some git commands in my clone of the org-mode git repo. I used

```
git log --oneline --grep='C-c C-v'
```

to find commits that mention that key combo. The actual commit was

> commit 3d8b6de2ad00220e164f226fb0dde5ada831d21b
>
> Author: Carsten Dominik
>
> Date:   Wed May 12 08:04:27 2010 +0200
>
> Free up the `C-c C-v' key for Org Babel
>
> TODO sparse trees are also accessible with `C-c / t'.

Isn't git wonderful?

Comment: Thanks Nick.  I was about to give up on Emacs and org-mode, just because of a bad tutorial.
Nice find on the git repo!

Comment: No, don't do that! A lot of the tutorials in Worg are at least partially outdated, because org-mode is fast-moving, but it's always worth a question here (or on the emacs SE site or on the mailing list: the latter is IMO a particularly congenial place to ask questions and the people on it are *very* helpful).

Comment: For those new to Emacs, here is the good tutorial, everything in it worked: http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/orgtutorial_dto.html

Comment: Also, the `C-c C-v` that tripped you up in the basic tutorial has been fixed (I assume after you sent a note to the mailing list - thanks for doing that).